# What is the functionality of conditional statement *= in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I found a piece of SQL code which uses *= as a conditional statement. Can some one provide some hint about it?

```
SELECT  *
FROM     TABLE1 A,TABLE2 B
WHERE    A.ID *= B.ID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an obsolete style [LEFT JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join).

You should use this instead

```
 select * 
 from
     TABLE1 A
          left join TABLE2 B 
          on A.ID = B.ID
```

You may also find [this](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/old-join-syntax-vs-new) useful when updating your code

Comment: Obsolete condition, and obsolete format with the tables comma separated.  MS keeps on making noise about not supporting that format forever, but who knows if they'll ever pull the trigger.

Comment: Wow, you had to dig way back to pull that answer out! +1

Comment: @BrianWhite The *= join is not supported above compatibility level 80 (SQL 2000)

Comment: Ah.  I guess they just make noise about select * from table1, table2b where a.id = b.id.